# Congruences in chinese remainder theorem

Tags: discrete-mathematics, modular-arithmetic, chinese-remainder-theorem

I'm trying to teach myself how to calculate xn, which is obtained thru linear congruence and given N

My example is:
99x==1(mod17)
Which is
14x==1(mod17)

Now here is my problem. When I try finding the result to the equation, my lowest result is -6 (14x6 = 17x5)

However, when I input the problem into wolfram or other solvers, result is 11. How so, am I doing something wrong entirely?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If we only allow positive integers as solutions $11$ is the smallest (which is congruent to $-6$ mod $17$)

Comment: Oh, so it's just about whether you allow negatives or only positives?

Comment: Yes, your result is actually correct if we want the minimum in absolute values.

Comment: Oh, I see, thanks. Just as a side question, in CRT you do take either of, correct?

Comment: Actually there are smaller solutions such as $-23$

Comment: @alps You can take every valid solution in the chinese remainder theorem because the result must only be the correct one modulo the product of the moduli.

Comment: @J.W.Tanner True, but not if we take the absolute value.

Comment: @Peter:  I agree; I was responding to a previous comment, which may have been since deleted or changed, but which I thought said that $-6$ is the smallest solution if we allow negatives (I do also agree that $-6$ is the solution with smallest absolute value)

Answer (score 1):

You can do it multiple ways: $$14x=17y+1\equiv 3y+1\equiv 0\bmod 14\implies y\equiv {-1\over 3}\equiv -{15\over 3}\equiv -5\equiv 9\bmod 14 \\17(9)+1=14(9+2)=14(11)\implies x\equiv 11\bmod 17$$

is probably the easiest though.